# SIR model parameter notation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, biology

I am reading on SIR models and I found [this article](http://bmcmedicine.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12916-015-0382-8)

In the article it has three groups as one without vaccination, one with only whole cell(wP) vaccination, and one with only acelluar(aP) vaccination. These groups are non-overlapping.

In the article it says,

> We assume those vaccinated with wP are completely immune to infection
>   . Those vaccinated with aP move into a vaccinated
>   class where they can become asymptomatically infected (that is, they
>   incur a direct benefit from vaccination because they will not develop
>   symptomatic disease). Unvaccinated individuals become infected with B.
>   pertussis at rate β and become symptomatic with probability σ, and aP
>   vaccinated individuals become asymptomatically infected at rate β. We
>   assume no difference in transmissibility between symptomatic and
>   asymptomatic individuals

Here, unlike `wP` vaccinated some of the `aP` vaccinated individuals can become asymptomatically infected.

The equations are

$\begin{array}{@{}rcl@{}} {}S'(t) &=& \mu \cdot (1-wP-aP)-\beta [I_{s}(t)+I_{a}(t)] S(t) {}\\ &&+ \omega R(t) -\nu S(t)  \end{array}$
$\begin{array}{@{}rcl@{}} {}I_{s}'(t) &=& \beta \sigma [I_{s}(t)+I_{a}(t)] S(t)-\gamma_{s} I_{s}(t) - \nu I_{s}(t) \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{@{}rcl@{}} {}I_{a}'(t) &=& \beta (1-\sigma) [I_{s}(t)+I_{a}(t)] S(t)+\beta [I_{s}(t)+I_{a}(t)] \\&&V(t)-\gamma_{a} I_{a}(t) - \nu I_{a}(t) \end{array}$
$\begin{array}{@{}rcl@{}} {}V'(t) &=& \mu \cdot aP-\beta [I_{s}(t)+I_{a}(t)] V(t)- \nu V(t) \end{array}$
$\begin{array}{@{}rcl@{}} {}R'(t) &=& \mu \cdot wP +\gamma_{s} I_{s}(t)+\gamma_{a} I_{a}(t) - \omega R(t) - \nu R(t)  \end{array}$

My question is is it reasonable to take the **same rate** $\beta$ for both the rate of unvaccinated getting infected and  for the rate in which `aP` vaccinated become asymptomatically infected.

Also how are these equations generated?Are there any specific methods to do them?

I would appreciate if someone can recommend good books for a beginner in mathematical biology to learn on SIR models, on how to develop ODE's and obtain basic reproduction number.